# Fortran - Insert Matrices into Other Matrices

Tags: matrix, fortran

I haven't made a code for it yet, however I will be making a Gauss-Seidel algorithm in Fortran, for solving very large matrices (actually to initiate the multi-gird method but that's irrelevant for this). As part of this, I wish to insert matrices into other matrices.

in MATLAB this is very simple, for example:

```
A=[1,2;3,4]
B=[A,A;A,A]
```

Outputs:

```
B =

1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4
1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4
```

as a 4x4 matrix.

However I have been having difficulties achieving the same with Fortran.

Please ignore the context - I don't require help with the GS/MG methods, I just need help embedding matrices (for other topics too), if at all possible!

Comment: What did you try in Fortran so far? please show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with array slices, e.g.

```
integer :: A(2,2)
integer :: B(4,4)

A(1,:) = [1, 2]
A(2,:) = [3, 4]

B(1:2,1:2) = A
B(3:4,1:2) = A
B(1:2,3:4) = A
B(3:4,3:4) = A
```

There [are proposals](https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals/issues/102) to introduce better syntax for this in a future Fortran standard.